# Python Error With Decorator: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, decorator

I don't understand how the decorator works in Python. I thought it is passing 1 function into another. But I get error with the below code. How do I modify it? Thank you

```
def mes(text):
    print ("Hello" + " " + str(text))
    

@mes
def name():
    return "Nicky"

print (mes(name()))
```

**Actual Result**

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

**Expected output**

"Hello Nicky"

Comment: `@mes` is simply not a valid decorator; it should return the decorated function, but it just returns `None`.

Comment: @awesoon: I don't understand the explanation in the other post. How should I modify my code? Thanks

Comment: Also, it is quite unusual for a decorator to use the decorated function's return value, though it's not wrong as such.

Comment: @stranger12309 quote from the second answer: `A decorator is a function that takes a function as its only parameter and returns a function.`. Your decorator doesn't return function. You can read comments to the code in that answer to understand how should it work

Comment: Probably also sort out the beginner errors; you call `print` twice, but reasonably only want one value to be printed. Should this happen in the decorated function (handy but clunky) or should the caller do it? You are also calling `mes` twice, once via the decoration, and then again in the final `print`.